# Can a female offer Pind-daan to her ancestors?

Tags: rituals, death, ancestry

Can a female offer pind-daan to her ancestors or any male can offer pind-daan ?  Is it essential that only male can offer pind-daan ?

Comment: As per Smriti Sangrah shradha kalpa lata,   sons, grandsons, great grandson, sister's son, brother, brother's son, father have the right to do Pind Daan. In absence of these or incase if both the sides of the families are destroyed (incase the above mentioned people are Nastik and uninterested ) **then one's wife, mother, daughter in law and sister too can do pinda daan and are considered Sapinda and Sodak.**